# Has and belongs to many with 3 Models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

What if I had 3 Models that I wanted to connect.

For example:

A user can have many different permissions for many different applications.

So I need a table to store:

```
user_id
permission_id
application_id
```

Is that possible with has_and_belongs_to_many?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I would do it with a has_many :through.

```
class Upa < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user 
  belongs_to :permission 
  belongs_to :application
end
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :permissions, :through => :upas
  has_many :applications, :through => :upas
end
class Permission < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users, :through => :upas
  has_many :applications, :through => :upas
end
class Application < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :permissions, :through => :upas
  has_many :users, :through => :upas
end
```

[examples of has_many :through](http://blog.hasmanythrough.com/2007/1/15/basic-rails-association-cardinality)

Basically any sort of relationship that you can describe with a classical one to one, one to many and many to many relationships in relational databases can be described in ActiveRecord.

Comment: Is it possible to provide an example how to use nested forms as well for this? I mean can I update an application and permissions through users?

Comment: [asciicasts nested model forms part 1 and 2](http://asciicasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1). Though you have to watch out for certain use cases in Rails 3. In Rails 2, you could have a new parent associate with an existing child (if for example, you have a new user you want to tie to an existing permission). In Rails 3, you cannot do this any longer as it is deemed a security risk, so your basic @parent.save would fail. [gist discussion about this](https://gist.github.com/897939/4da2160f28575d574c90c6fbc765b238900bd645)

Comment: So what does `user.permissions` mean in this particular case? Permissions for all applications? Let us say user has permission `P1` for application `A1`, and `P2` for application `A2`. What you get with `has_many :through` is `[P1, P2]`, what are you going to do with it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can have has_and_belongs_to_many relationship. More help can be found here http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html

Comment: HABTM in a three-way association? Are you serious?